# My GUI is not showing up fully

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, jframe

When I run my program, it only shows a few lines, and then it  shows gray under it. Can someone explain to me why this happens? I wanted the grid layout to have 8 rows, which should include the labels and text boxes. I am not sure why only a few of them appear.

```
public class Application extends JFrame {
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6, label7,
            label8;
    private JTextField text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6, text7, text8;

    public Application() {

        JFrame gui = new JFrame();
        gui.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 2));
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        gui.setTitle("Vacation Expenses");
        gui.setSize(500, 500);

        panel = new JPanel();
        gui.add(panel);

        label1 = new JLabel("Number of days on the trip");
        label2 = new JLabel("Amount of airfare");
        label3 = new JLabel("Amount of car rental fees");
        label4 = new JLabel(
                "Number of miles driven, if a private vehicle was used");
        label5 = new JLabel("Amount of parking fees, if any");
        label6 = new JLabel("Amount of taxi charges, if any");
        label7 = new JLabel("Conference or seminar registration fees, if any");
        label8 = new JLabel("Lodging charges, per night");

        text1 = new JTextField("0", 10);
        text2 = new JTextField("0", 10);
        text3 = new JTextField("0", 10);
        text4 = new JTextField("0", 10);
        text5 = new JTextField("0", 10);
        text6 = new JTextField("0", 10);
        text7 = new JTextField("0", 10);
        text8 = new JTextField("0", 10);

        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(text1);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(text2);
        panel.add(label3);
        panel.add(text3);
        panel.add(label4);
        panel.add(text4);
        panel.add(label5);
        panel.add(text5);

        // JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        // panel.add(button);

        gui.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be setting the `GridLayout` to your panel and not the frame. The panel is the container for the components, so should be the one with the `GridLayout`

Get rid of `gui.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 2));`

And use `panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 2));`

---

**Side Notes**

- Also note you haven't added all your components. You've only added five of each. You're forgetting to add the other three.
- Also, your class is *already* a `JFrame`. There's no need to create another one. Choose one or the other. Either use the instance `JFrame` and don't `extends JFrame` or `extend JFrame` and don't use the extra instance. I'd go with the former.
- Also, it's best to `pack()` your frame, instead of `setSize()`. The `pack()` should be done *after* adding all your components.
- Also, Swing apps should be run from the Event Dispatch Thread. You can accomplish this by wrapping the `main` method content in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`. See more at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough answer!!